# Typescript Compiler Does Not Know About ES6 Proxy Trap on Class

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-proxy

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract bar(): string;
}
```

I have some classes that extend `Foo`:

```
class Foo1 extends Foo {
    bar(): string { return 'foo1'; }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
    bar(): string { return 'foo2'; }
}
```

I have another class that I want to proxy all methods of `Foo` to a `Foo`.  This actually works fine, if I define all methods of `Foo` on this class.  But I would rather not do that.  I would prefer to have the methods of `Foo` defined on `Foo` and the compiler to know that `FooProxy` also implements those methods without actually having to implement them.  Is this possible?  The Proxy class looks something like this:

```
class FooProxy {
    public foo: Foo;

    constructor(foo: Foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        let handler = {
            get: function(target: FooProxy, prop: string, receiver: any) {
                if(Foo.prototype[prop] !== null) {
                    return target.foo[prop];
                }

                return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            }
        }
        return new Proxy(this, handler);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let f = new Foo1();
let fp = new FooProxy(f);
fp.bar();
```

Output:

```
error TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'FooProxy'.
```

This program actually runs in the playground, but `tsc` does not emit anything.  I just need to trick the compiler some how...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think in this case a class is the best approach you can just use a function to create the proxy and all will work as expected:

```
function createFooProxy(foo:Foo) : Foo { // Proxy<Foo> is compatible with Foo
    let handler = {
        get: function(target: Foo, prop: keyof Foo, receiver: any) {
            if(Foo.prototype[prop] !== null) {
                return foo[prop];
            }

            return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
        }
    }
    return new Proxy(foo, handler);
}
```

If you are set on using the class approach, you can fake a base class:

```
function fakeBaseClass<T>() : new() => Pick<T, keyof T>{ // we use a pick to remove the abstract modifier
    return class {} as any
}

class FooProxy extends fakeBaseClass<Foo>(){
    private foo: Foo; // I would make this private as it is not really accessible on what the constructor of FooProxy returns (maybe remove it as I see no use for it)

    constructor(foo: Foo) {
        super();
        this.foo = foo;
        let handler = {
            get: function(target: FooProxy, prop: keyof Foo, receiver: any) {
                if(Foo.prototype[prop] !== null) {
                    return target.foo[prop];
                }

                return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
            }
        }
        return new Proxy(this, handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer works and I thank you for it.  I ended up using the fake base class because I couldn't get the function to work correctly in the context of `FooProxy` being an Angular service, and `createFooProxy` being the service provider.  In this case I want to return `new Proxy(this, handler)` instead of `new Proxy(foo, handler)` because I need the `FooProxy` to retain its own properties and methods.  The error thrown is `FooProxy` has no properties in common with type 'Foo'.  Dependency injection also confuses the issue somewhat.  If you have any additional wisdom about that, great!

Comment: I'm curious why `Foo.prototype[prop]` would ever be null (as opposed to undefined or some other value).  In what scenario does it fall down to the `Reflect.get` approach? And I guess the opposite question as well: can you just do `Reflect.get` and cut the prototype approach?

Answer (score 7):

As an addition to the accepted answer I want to share a solution that can be used for more simple cases where you simply want to be able to proxy to any method or property (either a trap in the handler or something that actually exists on the actual target). The solution is based on using an "index signature", read more on that topic here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

I hope it will be useful for others ending up at this great question:

```
const handler = {
  get: (target: object, property: string, receiver: any) => {
    // define custom traps here:
    if (property === "trap") {
      // ... do something ...
    }

    // optional test whether property exists using the Reflect class:
    if (!Reflect.has(target, property)) {
      throw Error(`Property ${property} does not exist`);
    }
    // proxy to the target using the Reflect class:
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
};
```

I will show two solutions:

**1.** create a factory and an interface:

```
// Any property is allowed in this interface using the following index signature:
interface FooInterface {
  [key: string]: any;
}

// From the factory we return the FooInterface 
const proxyFactory = (target: Foo): FooInterface => {
  return new Proxy(target, handler);
};
```

**2.** create a class with an index signature and return the proxy directly from the class constructor

```
class FooProxy {
  [key: string]: any;
  constructor(target: Foo) {
    return new Proxy(target, handler);
  }
}
```

Can be used like this where all possible methods and properties you want to build a trap for inside the handler will be recognized:

```
const fooProxy = proxyFactory(foo);
```

or

```
const fooProxy = new FooProxy(foo);
```

No more messages complaining:

> Property '*...property name...*' does not exist on type 'Proxy'.

So anything can be called and trapped now:

```
const returnedFromMethod = fooProxy.anyMethod();
const property = fooProxy.anyProperty;
```

You can of course refine your interface, the example is simply to demonstrate a solution for all methods and properties.